# How do VSOnline Automated Test Runs/Builds Differ From Local?

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, azure-devops

I have unit tests that looks up a configuration file in a particular folder by determining the project path:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets the project path of the given type. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetProjectPath(Type type)
{
    var dll = new FileInfo(type.Assembly.Location);
    if (dll.Directory == null || // ...\Solution\Project\bin\Build 
        dll.Directory.Parent == null || // ...\Solution\Project\bin
        dll.Directory.Parent.Parent == null || // ...\Solution\Project
        dll.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent == null) // ...\Solution
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to find Project Path for " + type.FullName);
    }

    // Class Name, Project Name, Version, Culture, PublicKeyTyoken
    // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
    var projectName = type.AssemblyQualifiedName.Split(',')[1].Trim();
    var projectPath = Path.Combine(dll.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, projectName);

    if (!Directory.Exists(projectPath))
    {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Unable to find Project Path for {0} at {1}", type.FullName, projectPath));  
    }

    return projectPath;
}
```

This works great on dev machines, but when the VSOnline Build kicks off, the unit test fails, saying it can't find the project path.  This leads me to believe that either VSOnline Builds on one machine, and unit tests on another, or it's directory structure is somehow different, or the unit test doesn't have rights to read the file system...

Anyone have any insight into what could be the problem?

Comment: As an aside, a configuration file represents an external dependency. I would consider mocking it so that your tests are not dependent on it.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, @DanielMann, but I'm not sure that's possible.  The config file lists the directory of Serialized XML files to use to mock responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When VSOnline performs a build, the source files are located at `c:\a\src\Branch Name\`, but when it builds, it builds to the `c:\a\bin` folder.  I'm guessing this is done to help minimize any long path name errors.  The build is performed on the same server but the output is different than running it locally.

This required some changes in my method GetProjectPath method:

```cs
string solutionFolder = null;

if (dll.Directory == null || // ...\Solution\Project\bin\Build 
    dll.Directory.Parent == null || // ...\Solution\Project\bin
    dll.Directory.Parent.Parent == null || // ...\Solution\Project
    dll.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent == null) // ...\Solution
{
    if (dll.DirectoryName == @"C:\a\bin")
    {
        // Build is on VSOnline.  Redirect to other c:\a\src\Branch Name
        var s = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(true);
        for (var i = 0; i < s.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            var fileName = s.GetFrame(i).GetFileName();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                // File name will be in the form of c:\a\src\Branch Name\project\filename.  Get everything up to and including the Branch Name
                var parts = fileName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                solutionFolder = Path.Combine(parts[0] + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(solutionFolder))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to find Project Path for " + type.FullName + ".  Assembly Located at " + type.Assembly.Location + sb);
    }
}
else
{
    solutionFolder = dll.Directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
}
```